# Disappearing widgets in ubuntu 11.10 with using cairo in gtk2.0

Tags: ubuntu, gtk, repaint, cairo, ubuntu-11.10

This is my first question on Stack overflow.

Iam facing a problem after moving from Arch Linux to Ubuntu 11.10.
The problem Iam having is disappearing widgets whenever the active widget, ie button,etc is clicked.
if the active button is clicked all others widgets disappear except the button that was clicked. Then moving the mouse over the disappeared buttons causes them to re appear again.
But clicking the button then cause the rest of the widgets to disappear again.

I have put a small example of the problem Iam facing, not sure if its a gtk or a Cairo repaint issue. But this problem does not occur if I remove the cairo graphics from the code.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cairo.h>
//gcc -Wall -Werror -g repaint_problem.c -o repaint_problem `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`

void screen_changed(GtkWidget *widget, GdkScreen *old_screen, gpointer userdata)
{
    GdkScreen *screen = gtk_widget_get_screen(widget);
    GdkColormap *colormap = gdk_screen_get_rgba_colormap(screen);

    if (!colormap)
    {
        printf(" Your screen does not support alpha channels! >:-P\n");
        colormap = gdk_screen_get_rgb_colormap(screen);
    }

    gtk_widget_set_colormap(widget, colormap);
}

gboolean W_expose(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventExpose *event, gpointer userdata)
{
    cairo_t *cr = gdk_cairo_create(widget->window);
    cairo_pattern_t *pat1;

    cairo_set_source_rgba (cr, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0); /* transparent */

    /* draw the background */
    cairo_set_operator (cr, CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
    cairo_paint (cr);

    gshort x1 , y1 , x2 , y2;
    x1=0;
    y1=0;
    x2=400;
    y2=200;

    cairo_move_to(cr, x1+6, y1);
    cairo_arc(cr, x2-9, y1+10, 10, 270 * (M_PI / 180), 360 * (M_PI / 180));
    cairo_arc(cr, x2-9, y2-10, 10, 0 * (M_PI / 180), 90 * (M_PI / 180));
    cairo_arc(cr, x1+10, y2-10, 10, 90 * (M_PI / 180), 180 * (M_PI / 180));
    cairo_arc(cr, x1+10, y1+10, 10, 180 * (M_PI / 180), 270 * (M_PI / 180));
    cairo_stroke_preserve(cr);
    pat1 = cairo_pattern_create_linear(0, y1, 0, y2);
    cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba(pat1, 0.05, 0.35, 0.38, 0.82, 1);
    cairo_pattern_add_color_stop_rgba(pat1, 0.9,0.67, 0.78, 0.97 ,0.9);
    cairo_set_source(cr, pat1);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    cairo_pattern_destroy(pat1);    
    cairo_destroy(cr);
    g_print("redrawing\n");
    return FALSE;
}


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window, *fixed, *button[3];
  gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Cairo Dissappearing Button Act :-P");
  gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 0);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (window, 400, 200);

    // commenting out the line below will stop the cairo repainting and also stop the problem!
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "expose-event", G_CALLBACK(W_expose), NULL);

    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "screen-changed", G_CALLBACK(screen_changed), NULL);
    gtk_widget_set_app_paintable(window, TRUE);
    screen_changed(window, NULL, NULL);

  fixed = gtk_fixed_new ();

    gint i;
    for(i = 0 ; i<3 ; i++)
    {
        button[i]=gtk_button_new();
        gtk_widget_set_size_request (button[i], 40, 40); 
        gtk_fixed_put (GTK_FIXED (fixed), button[i], (i+1)*50, 40);
    }

  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), fixed);

  g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy",G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you compiling and linking with GTK 2 or 3? `expose-event` doesn't exist anymore in GTK 3, so maybe when you switched to Ubuntu you accidentally switched from 2 to 3?

Comment: Hmm, I cannot reproduce your described problem. I see three buttons, and nothing disappears when I press any of them. Maybe it has something to do with setting the window paintable? (ie. maybe gtk expects you to paint its child widgets manually too)